# Handling Cancel Button in Yes/No/Cancel Messagebox in FormClosing Method

Tags: c#, .net, messagebox

I put a **Yes/No/Cancel Messagebox** in **FormClosing** Method of my form. and now this is Message box text: *Do You Want to Save Data?*

I am not a profesional and not know how to handle if user clicked **Cancel** Button?
Exactly the result of clicking on Cancel Button must be The form remain open.
 How to prevent Closing my form in **FormClosing** method?

I wrote So far: ;)

```
DialogResult dr = MessageBoxFarsi.Show("Do You Want to Save Data?","",MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

//...
else if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    ???
}
```

Please Help me to complete my code!
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FormClosing has a Boolean parameter which, if set to True when the function returns, will cancel closing the form, IIRC.

EDIT: For example,

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    // Set e.Cancel to Boolean true to cancel closing the form
}
```

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

Actually I think you are missing Event handler, oh you can not turn to that even without an even handler. You must add an event with an event handler like this.

```
private void myform_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBoxFarsi.Show("Do You Want to Save Data?","",MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

    if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel) 
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
    else if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        //TODO: Save
    }
}

//now add a default constructor 
public myform()  // here use your form name.
{
    this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(myform_Closing); 
}
```

Forgive me if there are some wrongs spellings in this code because i didn't write it in c# and copy paste here. I just wrote it in here. :)

Answer (score 7):

You could have something like the following:

```
if(dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
else if(dr == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //Save the data
}
```

The above code should only close the form if you choose yes or no, and will save data when you choose yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to quit?", "Attention!!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
   //this block will be executed only when Yes is selected
   MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
}
else
{
  //this block will be executed when No/Cancel is selected
  //the effect of selecting No/Cancel is same in MessageBox (particularly in this event)
}
```

If needed same you can do for the `No` and `Cancel` Button click using `DialogResult` class

Answer (score 0):

you should try this function

```
public DialogResult msgClose(string msg)
{
     return MessageBox.Show(msg, "Close", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
}
```

and used like this.

```
private void frm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
     if (conn.msgClose("Application close?") == DialogResult.No)
         e.Cancel = true;
     else
     {
         this.Close();
     }
}
```